# How do I connect to google calendar's API using Visual Studio? (C#)

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I've spent much more time researching this topic than I would like to admit, but the instructions are incredibly complex to me. I'm developing a program with a calendar GUI, in which the user can select a day, and type an event he/she might have that day. Once done, I want to be able to import the user's data into a google calendar I have created. How can I do this? If you can, I would GREATLY appreciate a simplified answer, seeing as I'm a student, not a professional. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  If you have an attempt (no matter how ugly) post it and ask specific questions.

Comment: I found code for C# on the [google developers website](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet#prerequisites) what are you having issues with?

Answer (score 1):

Google has a [library in .NET to connect to Calendar](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/calendar/v3).

There is some [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/latest/annotated.html), and you can find the [API's documentation itself here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/).

You can find [an example here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet).

Comment: That helps tremendously, however these instructions are for a console based application, and I'm working with a windows form application. Is there a way I can make this work with my GUI?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow the Google Calendar API [.NET Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet) to add a Google Calendar integration to an ASP.NET MVC application.

Essentially, you will need to download an authentication file (either JSON or P12) from the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=calendar) and use it to create a credential:

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   string credPath = @"/location/to/store/credentials"
   UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
   CalendarService.Scope.Calendar,
   "user",
   CancellationToken.None,
   new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}
```

With the default settings in the developer's console, you'll end up launching an [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) authentication pop-up each time you need permission from a new user. If they give you permission in that screen, use the credential to authorize a `CalendarService` object:

```
// Create Google Calendar API service.
var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "Your Cool Calendar Application",
});
```

The service will then allow you to execute Create/Read/Update/Delete requests for the user you are currently authenticated for:

```
Event newEvent = new Event()
{
    Summary = "new event",
    Start = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-11T09:00:00"),
        TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    End = new EventDateTime()
    {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse("2016-07-11T10:00:00"),
        TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
};

Event createdEvent = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").Execute();
```

You can find more information about what events are available for different Google Calendar objects in [the API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/) and more information on the .NET wrappers [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/calendar/v3) (though the .NET examples aren't very complete; you're better off looking at SO). You can create these objects from anywhere in your application.